# Can't recover from panic - defer is entirely skipped

Tags: go, recover, panic

When using io.Copy with an invalid writer, I get a panic - that's expected. However I can't recover when this is the case. My deferred recover is completely bypassed.  Here is the code:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "runtime"
    "runtime/debug"

    "cloud.google.com/go/storage"
)

func main() {
    var (
        ctx      = context.Background()
        fromFile = "blah.txt"
        bucket   = "blah-bucket"
        path     = "blah-path"
    )

    defer func() {
        if result := recover(); result != nil {
            buf := make([]byte, 1<<16)
            length := runtime.Stack(buf, false)
            log.Fatalf("PANIC RECOVER: %v\nSTACK: \n%s", result, buf[:length])
            debug.PrintStack()
        }
    }()

    err := FakeUpload(ctx, fromFile, bucket, path)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("HELLO")
}

func FakeUpload(ctx context.Context, fromFile, toBucket, toPath string) (err error) {
    var (
        file   *os.File
        client *storage.Client
        wc     *storage.Writer
    )

    defer func() {
        for _, c := range []io.Closer{wc, file} {
            if c != nil {
                err = c.Close()
                if err != nil {
                    return
                }
            }
        }
    }()

    file, err = os.Open(fromFile)
    if err != nil {
        err = fmt.Errorf("problem opening file %v: %v", fromFile, err)
        return
    }

    wc = client.Bucket(toBucket).Object(toPath).NewWriter(ctx)

    _, err = io.Copy(wc, file) // THE UNRECOVERABLE PANIC HAPPENS HERE

    return
}
```

The panic being:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xc0000005 code=0x0 addr=0x0 pc=0x9e0fa8]

goroutine 21 [running]:
cloud.google.com/go/storage.(*Writer).open.func1(0xc000161200, 0xc0002721e0, 0xc000150388, 0xc000290e20, 0x1, 0x1)
    C:/Users/xxxx/go/pkg/mod/cloud.google.com/go/storage@v1.14.0/writer.go:128 +0x248
created by cloud.google.com/go/storage.(*Writer).open
    C:/Users/xxxx/go/pkg/mod/cloud.google.com/go/storage@v1.14.0/writer.go:118 +0x6ce
Process exiting with code: 0
```

```
module main

go 1.15

require cloud.google.com/go/storage v1.14.0
```

```
go version go1.15.10 windows/amd64
```

The kicker is, if it panics elsewhere, for example I point to an invalid file, it'll panic, and the deferred recover properly captures it.

This has me baffled.  Any idea?

Comment: Show where where exactly the panic is happening. You cannot recover from panics in other goroutines, which is the only possibility if your recover is not executed.

Comment: @JimB I've updated the code to reflect where the panic is. The panic is where the `_, err = io.Copy(wc, file)` runs.

Comment: @FrankBryce This is a fairly small sample, with it only being 69 lines. Moving the defer into `FakeUpload`, still results in an unrecovered panic.

Comment: @ymerej, there is nothing that can panic on that line. What is the exact panic message and source location?

Comment: @JimB I updated again with the panic message. But it is panicking there. I literally debugged one line at a time, and that's where it blows up.

Comment: The panic is happening inside a goroutine made in cloud.google.com/go/storage, you cannot recover that.

Comment: @JimB I think it has something to do with Google's storage writer. I made the wc equal nil and comment out `wc = client.Bucket(toBucket).Object(toPath).NewWriter(ctx)`, it then recovers properly.

Comment: @JimB If that's the case where cloud.google.com/go/storage is creating a goroutine, isn't that poor code on their side? How can one catch that? If I have a daemon service running and that get's panicked there, it literally quits the app without any kind of way to indicate what happened because I can't catch it to log it.

Comment: @paladin I can agree, hence why I'm attempting to capture that error and have a way to present it.  In this case, it's obvious what's wrong, but who knows what may be in that subroutine that could panic. If that package deemed it didn't like files that were the size 5434 bytes and panicked on those, you may never know it until it was out in the wild, hence why you should be able to capture it.

Comment: A panic is normally used to indicate a programmer error, and is meant to crash the application. You are not expected to catch panics like this

Comment: The only why to be able to 'recover' from such fatal bugs is to fully encapsable this routine in its own process. Because, what you here are asking is in real "How to recover from irreversable memory corruption?", answer, you can't recover, you may only ignore.

Comment: @JimB I see your point even though I don't necessarily agree with Google's or Golang's approach on this. They are expecting everyone to essentially write perfect code, but anyone can throw a panic in any goroutine, and the panic will be lost into oblivion. You'll just have an abrupt end to your logging with no indication as to what went wrong. Writing perfect code isn't going to happen otherwise there would be no stackoverflow.

Comment: @paladin I think you are completely missing the point.

Comment: @ymerej maybe you misunderstand the meaning of `panic`. It should not be considered like an Exception in other languages. It is reserved for cases where something went really wrong, and the program can't continue correctly.  In Go we don't have the choice of saying "I don't know when or where my program will crash, but if it does, I want to keep going, regardless of the consequences!"

Comment: @HymnsForDisco I do understand a panic. I don't mind that the app crashes because it can't go on. But I think folks keep misunderstanding my point. There should be a way to log that. Exiting an application without any indication of what went wrong is not good and not useful at all to anyone investigating. What purpose does it serve to kill an application and not say what happened?

It's not unreasonable to let the user know why the application crashed.

Comment: The panic will be output to stderr, so you will need to look up how to redirect stderr to a log file on your OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, as you can read in the comments above, is that `cloud.google.com/go/storage` writer is creating a goroutine, and throwing the panic in there. GO does not allow you to recover from another goroutine.